# How do I find Capybara::Node::Element that corresponds to Selenium::WebDriver::Element

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, mapping, capybara

There is a node, that I find by coordinates and wish to execute a relative xpath query on it, so I probably need a Capybara object (`Capybara::Node::Element`) for `.find(:xpath`, but the object I get from `evaluate_script("document.elementFromPoint` is a Selenium object (`Selenium::WebDriver::Element`).

Answer (score 1):

Capybara::Node::Element is just a wrapper around the native node (that also stores how it was found so it can be auto reloaded). Snce you won't be using the auto reload behavior you can probably just do

```
Capybara::Node::Element.new(current_session, element_from_evaluate, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.attribute("class")` for getting class of element then produce the `css_selector` and finally `find(:css, css_selector)` returns `Capybara::Node::Element`.

```
irb#1(main):139:0* p = evaluate_script("document.elementFromPoint(1000, 240)")
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x5cc6ed77c104c804 id="{0b83a9a2-ff2c-fe43-8518-38b7522c47a9}">
irb#1(main):140:0> c = p.attribute("class")
=> "col-xs-12 col-sm-4"
irb#1(main):141:0> cc = c.split(" ")
=> ["col-xs-12", "col-sm-4"]
irb#1(main):142:0> css = ""
=> ""
irb#1(main):143:0> cc.each { |cs| css << (".#{cs}")}
=> ["col-xs-12", "col-sm-4"]
irb#1(main):144:0> css
=> ".col-xs-12.col-sm-4"
irb#1(main):145:0> find(:css, css, :match => :first)
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]">
```

I think you can also use `:css` instead of `:xpath`